# Local Xampp Server doesn't differentiate php sessions from different users

Tags: php, session, networking, authentication, intranet

I am trying to build a intranet. I did a whole bunch of work until I realized that when I login to my intranet from my PC then on my Laptop I have the same session open. This is quite bad for a local intranet, imagine an admin logs in and every user in the network suddenly can open the intranet without having to log in.

I am using very simple php sessions but for whatever reason it doesn't allow me to differentiate between different network users. I have tried multiple other example codes and those have the same issue.

Here is for example one of them:

```
<?php  session_start(); ?> 
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['use'])) 
     {
        header("Location:home.php"); 
     }

    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
         $user = $_POST['user'];
         $pass = $_POST['pass'];

          if($user == "Admin" && $pass == "1234")
             {

              $_SESSION['use']=$user;


             echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.open("home.php","_self");</script>';

            }

            else
            {
                echo "invalid UserName or Password";        
            }
    }
     ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Login Page   </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table width="200" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>  UserName</td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="user" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> PassWord  </td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the page it goes to:

```
<?php   session_start();  ?>

<html>
  <head>
       <title> Home </title>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
      if(!isset($_SESSION['use']))
       {
           header("Location:Login.php");  
       }

          echo $_SESSION['use'];

          echo "Login Success";

          echo "<a href='logout.php'> Logout</a> "; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issues. First of all clear you cookies they stick very badly. Second of all if you have a session created and specify a custom id then you will have this issue. Since both hosts will use the same id.